# Undo deletion of remote branch in git?

Tags: git

In a git repository I can delete the master branch with:

```
git push origin :master
```

I delete the remote master branch. Since a branch is simply a pointer to a commit in the history graph the actual data is not deleted. But how do I undo a delete of a remote branch, e.g the above master branch?

Further lets assume that I also deleted my local master branch.

Answer (score 5):

You simply need to push the original commit back to that branch:

```
git push origin <commit-ID>:master
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on "original commit"?

Comment: But what if you forget the SHA/Commit-ID for the commit that master was pointing to?

Comment: You can of course also specify the hash by using another branch, e.g. your local branch: `git push origin master:master`.

Comment: @Makoto: The commit that you want the branch to refer to.

Comment: @u123: That is exactly the bit of information that you actually deleted (the commit ID).  If you can't find that anywhere, you have a problem.  You can look in the output of the deletion command (if you have that), the local branch, other branches, or the history of any branch (`git reflog`) to try to figure out what it might be.

Comment: @SLaks: Ok so what you are saying is that its not dangerous to do  push origin :master since you can always use e.g. the reflog to find the commit-ID that the master label originally pointed to?

Comment: @u123: Yes, although I don't know whether the reflog is ever trimmed.  Try `git reflog origin/master`